# ErrorException Missing required parameters laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am having an issue by modifying the route for a view. I want instead of /company/id to show /company/id/name

the route:

```
Route::get('/company/{id}/{name}', 'PagesController@showCompany')->name('company.detail');
```

show method in controller:

```
public function showCompany($id){
        $company = Company::find($id);
        return view('company.show')->with('company', $company);
    }
```

and in the view $companies is from a search controller - and it should get the results with a link to open the view

```
 @foreach($companies as $company)
                <a href="{{route('company.detail', $company->id, $company->company_name)}}">Show detail </a>
 @endforeach
```

if using only with id like /company/id works. What i am wrong?

Comment: You haven't updated your controller to accept `{name}` by the looks of it.

Comment: @JonStirling  why do you mean? you mean setting the showCompany($id,$name) like that?

Answer (score 0):

A simple an elegant way (i think) is:

```
{{route('company.detail', ['id' => $company->id, 'name' => strtolower(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $company->company_name))}}
```

You can have a friendly url name. I am sure that there are better solutions out there.

If you have more params in the route you can use an associative array and initialize each param name with a value.

the controller now is the same with the id.